# Artifactory satellite pass-though keepAlive

Tags: artifactory, keep-alive

we have 6 Artifactory Server (no HA cluster):
Artifactory satellite pass-though topology

Between all artifactory server we have firewalls to
connect each network together.

How it is possibly to configure between all artifactory servers keepAlive?
I want if one artifactory requests the other as uptream server they should send keep-alives
each other.

Any ideas?

Best regards
mobios

Answer (score 0):

If the use case is to get the status (running or not) of the upstream Artifactory server then you can either go with the [Router health check REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-HealthCheck) or [Artifactory health check REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SystemHealthPing)

Comment: The use case is:
Between the atifactorys are firewalls and i dont wont that they cut the connection off streams if they need to many time for the request. I want send keep-alives through the firewall to keep the connection stable.